# JPA 2 and Hibernate 3.5.1 MEMBER OF query doesnt work

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying the following JPQL and it fails misserably:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE 'admin' MEMBER OF u.roles");
List users = query.query.getResultList();
```

I get the following exception:

```
ERROR [main] PARSER.error(454) | <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT u FROM com.online.data.User u WHERE 'admin' MEMBER OF u.roles] ERROR [main] PARSER.error(454) | <AST>:0:0: expecting "from", found '<ASTNULL>'
...
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT u FROM com.online.data.User u WHERE 'admin' MEMBER OF u.roles]
```

I have Spring 3.0.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 3.5.1-Final and maven to glue dependencies.

User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "USER_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  private boolean enabled;

  @ElementCollection
  private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();

...
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- Reading annotation driven configuration -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
  <property name="maxWait" value="1000" />
  <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
  <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
   </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
   <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_comments">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="JpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>



</beans>
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

 <persistence-unit name="punit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />

</persistence>
```

pom.xml maven dependencies.

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
   <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
 <properties>
  <!-- Application settings -->
  <spring.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>3.5.1-Final</hibernate.version>
```

Im running a unit test to check the configuration and I am able to run other JPQL queries the only ones that I am unable to run are the IS EMPTY, MEMBER OF conditions.

The complete unit test is as follows:

TestIntegration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations =  { "/spring/dataLayer.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration
public class TestUserDaoImplIntegration {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Test
  public void shouldTest() throws Exception {
    try {
//WORKS
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE 'admin' in elements(u.roles)"); 
List users = query.query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
    try {
//DOES NOT WORK
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE 'admin' MEMBER OF u.roles"); 
List users = query.query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query looks **perfectly fine** to me. For the record, this is what the JPA 2.0 specification writes about the `MEMBER OF` operator:

> #### 4.6.13 Collection Member Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator `MEMBER OF` in an collection_member_expression is as follows:
>
> ```
>    collection_member_expression ::=
>             entity_or_value_expression [NOT] MEMBER [OF] collection_valued_path_expression
>    entity_or_value_expression ::=
>             single_valued_object_path_expression |
>             state_field_path_expression |
>             simple_entity_or_value_expression
>    simple_entity_or_value_expression ::=
>             identification_variable |
>             input_parameter |
>             literal
> ```
>
> This expression tests whether the designated value is a member of
>   the collection specified by the
>   collection-valued path expression.
>
> Expressions that evaluate to
>   embeddable types are not supported in
>   collection member expressions. Support
>   for use of embeddables in collection
>   member expressions may be added in a
>   future release of this specification.
>
> If the collection valued path
>   expression designates an empty
>   collection, the value of the `MEMBER`
>   OF expression is `FALSE` and the value
>   of the `NOT MEMBER OF` expression is
>   `TRUE`. Otherwise, if the value of the
>   collection_valued_path_expression or entity_or_value_expression in the collection member expression is NULL
>   or unknown, the value of the
>   collection member expression is
>   unknown.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT p
> FROM Person p
> WHERE 'Joe' MEMBER OF p.nicknames
> ```

So, because I can't see anything wrong in your query, I've tested your code with EclipseLink<sup>1</sup> and the following snippet just works:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE 'admin' MEMBER OF u.roles");
List list = query.getResultList();
```

But fails indeed with Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.1-Final. This sounds like a bug, feel free to raise [a Jira issue](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH).

<sup>1</sup> Just in case, I used the following Maven profile (for the JPA provider):

```
  <profile>
    <id>eclipselink</id>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- optional - only needed if you are using JPA outside of a Java EE container-->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>              
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
```

And this is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

  <persistence-unit name="TestPu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">    
    <class>com.stackoverflow.q2688144.User</class>    
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true"/>    
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update:** reported in [HHH-5209](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5209)

Comment: Thanks I just thought that I was becoming insane.

Comment: @Ed_Zero You're clearly not :) Could you please update the question with a link to the Jira issue if you create one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

[Hibernate Bug #HHH-5209](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5209),
as workaround use the following syntax:

```
select user from User user where :role in elements(user.roles)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround... Could you point me to the workaround for is [not] empty operator?

Answer (score 4):

Your query is absolutely correct and should work. I ran into this same problem just today, and thanks to this post, was able to stop banging my head against the wall.

Since @ElementCollection is really a nice shortcut to a joined element with an intrinsic association, you can still use join semantics in your query.

To put that in better terms, you need to join your collection, and set a condition in the where.

To put that into something more concrete...

Your query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE 'admin' MEMBER OF u.roles
```

Can be written as:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r = 'admin'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think `member of` cannot be used with a `@ElementCollection` property.

Comment: There is nothing like that in the spec. `MEMBER OF` is supposed to work on collection (and it does) regardless of the annotation used.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Haven't had the chance to study the spec yet and it was just a wild guess.

Comment: There are so many things that are in the JPA spec, yet Hibernate just doesn't support it. How can an application server build around Hibernate ever be Java EE certified?